# How can I pass a Query String variable into the CAML of a jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, caml-query, query-string

I'm using Marc's SPServices jQuery library - the SPFilterDropDown script - to filter the items in a Lookup multi-select field on a New Item DVWP. It works fine if I stick some static text in there - but I'd like it to be dynamic.

I've tried a few versions.

```
var VARIABLE = $("#VARIABLE").html();
$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({  
relationshipList: "{LISTID}",  
relationshipListColumn: "COLUMN",  
columnName: "FORMCOLUMN",  
listName: "{LISTID}",  
noneText: "(None)",  
CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='VARIABLE' /><Value Type='Text'>'+ VARIABLE + '</Value></Eq>",  
completefunc: null,  
debug: true
});
```

The `//var VARIABLE = $("#VARIABLE").html();//` line is my attempt at making the dynamic piece work.

I've tried many variations on the CAML query:

```
- '+ VARIABLE + ' vs. {VARIABLE}
- Value Type='Text' vs. Value Type='Lookup'
- Eq vs. Contains
```

No luck. Looking for help.

Comment: perhaps you could add an example of the query string you're using too.

Comment: Sorry - it parsed it out - I'll post today. Marc came to the rescue.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using single quotes around the `'+ VARIABLE +'` instead of double quotes? I'll be honest, I don't know the jQuery library you're using, but it seems like you're expecting it to parse a strange combination of XML and jscript.

Comment: Double quotes indeed were required - while searching the Web for solutions, I saw various forms of syntax so I was trying single quotes when I first posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing is happening, then it's likely your query string code block isn't working properly.

Look into his [SPGetQueryString](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetQueryString&referringTitle=Documentation) operation.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
 var yourVar = queryStringVals.theQSParam; 
    $().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({   
    relationshipList: "{LISTID}",   
    relationshipListColumn: "COLUMN",   
    columnName: "FORMCOLUMN",   
    listName: "{LISTID}",   
    noneText: "(None)",   
    CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='VARIABLE' /><Value Type='Text'>'+ yourVar + '</Value></Eq>",   
    completefunc: null,   
    debug: true 
    });
```

Comment: I came in to post more or less exactly what you posted here (plus double quotes around the variable in the CAML) - adding the SPGetQueryString made everything happy.